# How to extend JAXB generated class avoiding use of objects for numbers using primitive types instead?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Our XSD contains a location type using default values. Thus the generated code will use `Double` wrapper object instead of primitive `double`. Unfortunately we cannot modify the schema to keep the API stable.
Now we want to instantiate a huge amount (>10M) objects of that type. But this will consume relative huge amount of RAM. So we are looking for a way to use primitive `double` to avoid the wrapper objects.

Section from our XSD:

```
<complexType name="Location">
    <attribute name="x" type="double" default="NaN"/>
    <attribute name="y" type="double" default="NaN"/>
</complexType>
<element name="Location" type="location:Location" />
```

Generated code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Location")
public class Location {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "x")
    protected Double x;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "y")
    protected Double y;

    public double getX() {
        if (x == null) {
            return java.lang.Double.NaN;
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    }

    public void setX(Double value) {
        this.x = value;
    }

    public double getY() {
        if (y == null) {
            return java.lang.Double.NaN;
        } else {
            return y;
        }
    }

    public void setY(Double value) {
        this.y = value;
    }
}
```

We tried to extend the Location class, by putting it into same package but at main instead of generated source directory:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlType(name = "Location")
public class InternalLocation extends Location {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "x")
    private double x;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "y")
    private double y;

    public InternalLocation() {
    }

    public InternalLocation(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public void setX(Double x) {
        // TODO null => NaN
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void setY(Double y) {
        // TODO null => NaN
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

But the resulting XML will not contain the x and y value:

```
<ns2:Location xmlns:ns2="http://test.com/location" x="1.0" y="2.0"/>
```

vs.

```
<ns2:Location xmlns:ns2="http://test.com/location"/>
```

Using `Marshaller` from `JAXBContext.newInstance("com.test.location");`

What can we do to use `InternalLocation`?

- different instantiation of `JAXBContext`?
- overwrite injected `com.test.location.Location$JaxbAccessorF_x`?

Or is there some other way to avoid the wrapper objects?

One important thing I should mention: We want to use that within CXF web service but CXF is using JAXB too.

PS: We do not want to use different data representation for internal and external usage.

PPS: We just require propper serialization (on the server side). We do not require deserialization into InternalLocation (on the client side).

Comment: What if you use `JAXBContext.newInstance( InternalLocation.class )` ?

Comment: Have you considered writing your own Location class and maybe using an XmlAdapter?

Comment: @svasa Using `JAXBContext.newInstance(InternalLocation.class)` revealed a problem with `InternalLocation`: `Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://test.com/location}Location"`. so we updated using `@XmlType(name = "InternalLocation")`. Then the XML contains the desired parameters: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:Location xmlns:ns2="http://test.com/location" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:InternalLocation" x="1.0" y="2.0"/>` but we don’t want to have different `xsi:type`...